# Counting the numbers that yield a constant when summed

Tags: algorithm

I was initially trying to code an algo that can rapidly count k numbers that yield s when summed. These numbers must lie in the interval from 0 to d. For instance, taking d=2, k=2 and s=3, the possible combinations are (1,2) and (2,1). So there are two 1 and two 2. For higher d, k and s this becomes very complicated. I could do this with this code:

```
f[k_, d_, s_] := Module[{x, ls, z},
   x = 0; ls = {};
   Do[
    z = IntegerDigits[x, d + 1, k];
    If[Total[z] == s, AppendTo[ls, z]];
    x++,
    {(d + 1)^k}];
   Return[Table[Count[Flatten[ls], i], {i, 0, d}]]];
```

But this is very slow for big numbers. Furthermore, I realized meanwhile that I need a sum over a product. See my answer below.

Comment: Have you seen the function: IntegerPartitions?

Comment: Yes, I know this function but it does not yield what I am looking for. What is your suggestion how to use it?

Comment: Is this code `f[k_,d_,s_]:=Select[Tuples[Range[0,d],k],Total[#]==s&];` MUCH less complicated? Does it produce EXACTLY the same result for EVERY case? If you carefully restart MMA each time so that you completely clear the history and cache before you use `Timing[]`, is this code even a little bit faster? By avoiding all those `AppendTo` it seems like it should be a little bit faster, but careful timing without the cache messing with the answer, seems like it should be. Next, exactly how big do these numbers really need to get?

Comment: IntegerPartitions will deliver sorted tuples with origin 1. For origin 0 you need to subtract: 1. And finally you would need to get all permutations of the tuples.

Comment: Thanks Bill, this code is about twice as fast. Indeed, the numbers are are not so big but the function is used repeatedly in recurring functions. I guess that when defining it as ```f[k_,d_,s_]:=f[k,d,s]=...``` it will run faster, remembering the already calculated numbers.

Comment: `Tuples` is going to generate a lot of tuples that are discarded. Time this `d=5;k=4;s=8;padding=Table[0,{k-1}];pad[v_]:=If[Length[v]==k,v,Take[Join[v, padding],k]];f[k_,d_,s_]:=Flatten[Map[Permutations,Map[pad,IntegerPartitions[ s,k,Range[d]]]],1];f[k,d,s]` for the typical `k,d,s` that you are using and see if it is faster or slower. And test this brutally to make certain that it is correct for all cases.

Comment: @Bill: Wow, this is fast. Calculated this in 0.5 sec. with k = 8; d = 10; s = 30; while the code with Tuples is still calculating while I am writing and using all of my 32 Giga of memory... Thanks a lot, you are a genius.